# Load json data First time and use data appropriate the spinner option selected

Tags: android, json, arraylist, hashmap, android-spinner

I load json data when fragment start

See my webservice

```
    {
Data: [
{
id: "1",
Name: "Shirt/Tees",
Dry_cleaning: "49",
Wash_Iron: "19",
Wash: "15",
Iron: "8"
},
{
id: "2",
Name: "Kurta(short)",
Dry_cleaning: "49",
Wash_Iron: "19",
Wash: "20",
Iron: "5"
},
{
id: "3",
Name: "Kurta(Long)",
Dry_cleaning: "50",
Wash_Iron: "20",
Wash: "15",
Iron: "8"
},
{
id: "4",
Name: "Shorts",
Dry_cleaning: "50",
Wash_Iron: "19",
Wash: "15",
Iron: "5"
},
{
id: "5",
Name: "Trousers/Pyjamas",
Dry_cleaning: "55",
Wash_Iron: "30",
Wash: "20",
Iron: "8"
},
{
id: "6",
Name: "Jeans",
Dry_cleaning: "70",
Wash_Iron: "29",
Wash: "20",
Iron: "7"
},
{
id: "7",
Name: "Blazer",
Dry_cleaning: "150",
Wash_Iron: "19",
Wash: "25",
Iron: "5"
},
{
id: "8",
Name: "Leather_Jacket",
Dry_cleaning: "100",
Wash_Iron: "36",
Wash: "30",
Iron: "6"
},
{
id: "9",
Name: "Lungi/Dhoti(Long)",
Dry_cleaning: "100",
Wash_Iron: "15",
Wash: "12",
Iron: "13"
},
{
id: "10",
Name: "Waist_coat",
Dry_cleaning: "120",
Wash_Iron: "30",
Wash: "40",
Iron: "12"
},
{
id: "11",
Name: "Muffler/Cap/Gloves",
Dry_cleaning: "50",
Wash_Iron: "35",
Wash: "30",
Iron: "20"
},
{
id: "14",
Name: "Bathrobe",
Dry_cleaning: null,
Wash_Iron: "15",
Wash: "5",
Iron: "10"
},
{
id: "16",
Name: "Sherwani",
Dry_cleaning: "100",
Wash_Iron: "50",
Wash: "30",
Iron: "10"
}
],
message: "Values"
}
```

What i want is when i select the spinner option DryClean ,Wash,Wash&Iron and iron do not call the AsyncTask just show the ArrayList in listview

[image]
Please anyone help me for this

Here is my code

**ManFragment.java**

```
public class ManFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootView;
//Dry
public static String TAG_ITEM_MAN = "Name";
public static String TAG_PRICE_DRY = "Dry_cleaning";
public static String TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON = "Wash_Iron";
public static String TAG_PRICE_WASH = "Wash";
public static String TAG_PRICE_IRON = "Iron";
public static String Name, Price_Dry, price_wash_iron, price_wash, price_iron;

static TextView ItemName, ItemPrice;
public static int Cat_Position;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> WashList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> WashIronList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> IronList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


ListView list;
ProgressDialog pdialog;

static Spinner Spin_Man;

public ManFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.man_listView);
    Spin_Man = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_man);


    new DryData().execute();

    Spin_Man.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

            try {


                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        getView();

                        break;
                    case 1:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        getView();

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        getView();

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        getView();

                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

    new DryData().execute();

    return rootView;
}


private class DryData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pdialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pdialog.setCancelable(true);
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        String jsonStr = jp.makeServiceCall(url_dry, JSONParser.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("Data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobjin = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = jobjin.getString(TAG_ITEM_MAN);
                    String price_dry = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_DRY);
                    String price_wash_iron = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON);
                    String price_wash = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_WASH);
                    String price_iron = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_IRON);

                    HashMap<String, String> add_dry = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_dry.put(TAG_ITEM_MAN, name);
                    add_dry.put(TAG_PRICE_DRY, price_dry);
                    HashMap<String, String> add_wash_iron = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_wash_iron.put(TAG_ITEM_MAN, name);
                    add_wash_iron.put(TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON, price_wash_iron);
                    HashMap<String, String> add_wash = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_wash_iron.put(TAG_ITEM_MAN, name);
                    add_wash.put(TAG_PRICE_WASH, price_wash);
                    HashMap<String, String> add_iron = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_iron.put(TAG_PRICE_IRON, price_iron);

                    DryList.add(add_dry);
                    WashList.add(add_wash);
                    WashIronList.add(add_wash_iron);
                    IronList.add(add_iron);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url_dry");

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pdialog.isShowing()) {
            pdialog.dismiss();
        }

        Filllist();
    }

}

public void Filllist() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cus adapter = new Cus();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class Cus extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_row, null);
        }
        ItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        ItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        Name = DryList.get(position).get(TAG_ITEM_MAN).toString();
        Price_Dry = DryList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_DRY).toString();
        price_wash_iron = WashIronList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON).toString();
        price_wash = WashList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_WASH).toString();
        price_iron = IronList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_IRON).toString();


        if (Cat_Position == 0) {
            //set item name
            ItemName.setText("" + Name);
            ItemPrice.setText("" + Price_Dry);
        } else if (Cat_Position == 1) {
            //set item name
            ItemName.setText("" + Name);
            ItemPrice.setText("" + price_wash_iron);
        } else if (Cat_Position == 2) {
            //set item name
            ItemName.setText("" + Name);
            ItemPrice.setText("" + price_wash);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: put getView(); method code.

Comment: Please show me some code

Comment: see you just call web service very first time when activity launched and after that you store data in arraylist or shared preferences and onclick just load the ArrayList to spinner.

Comment: Found the solution just put  Filllist() in every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution just put  Filllist(); in every case see my modified code

**ManFragment.java**

```
public class ManFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootView;
//Dry
public static String TAG_ITEM_MAN = "Name";
public static String TAG_PRICE_DRY = "Dry_cleaning";
public static String TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON = "Wash_Iron";
public static String TAG_PRICE_WASH = "Wash";
public static String TAG_PRICE_IRON = "Iron";
public static String Name, Price_Dry, price_wash_iron, price_wash, price_iron;
public static String url_dry = "http://openspace.tranetech.com/mis/Laundry/men_dry.php";
static TextView ItemName, ItemPrice;
public static int Cat_Position;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> WashList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> WashIronList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> IronList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


ListView list;
ProgressDialog pdialog;

static Spinner Spin_Man;

public ManFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.man_listView);
    Spin_Man = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_man);


    new DryData().execute();

    Spin_Man.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

            try {


                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        Filllist();
                        getView();

                        break;
                    case 1:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        Filllist();
                        getView();

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        Filllist();
                        getView();

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        Cat_Position=position;
                        Filllist();
                        getView();

                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

    new DryData().execute();

    return rootView;
}


private class DryData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pdialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pdialog.setCancelable(true);
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        String jsonStr = jp.makeServiceCall(url_dry, JSONParser.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("Data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobjin = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = jobjin.getString(TAG_ITEM_MAN);
                    String price_dry = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_DRY);
                    String price_wash_iron = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON);
                    String price_wash = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_WASH);
                    String price_iron = jobjin.getString(TAG_PRICE_IRON);

                    HashMap<String, String> add_dry = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_dry.put(TAG_ITEM_MAN, name);
                    add_dry.put(TAG_PRICE_DRY, price_dry);
                    HashMap<String, String> add_wash_iron = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_wash_iron.put(TAG_ITEM_MAN, name);
                    add_wash_iron.put(TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON, price_wash_iron);
                    HashMap<String, String> add_wash = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_wash_iron.put(TAG_ITEM_MAN, name);
                    add_wash.put(TAG_PRICE_WASH, price_wash);
                    HashMap<String, String> add_iron = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    add_iron.put(TAG_PRICE_IRON, price_iron);

                    DryList.add(add_dry);
                    WashList.add(add_wash);
                    WashIronList.add(add_wash_iron);
                    IronList.add(add_iron);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url_dry");

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pdialog.isShowing()) {
            pdialog.dismiss();
        }

        Filllist();
    }

}

public void Filllist() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cus adapter = new Cus();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class Cus extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_row, null);
        }
        ItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        ItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        Name = DryList.get(position).get(TAG_ITEM_MAN).toString();
        Price_Dry = DryList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_DRY).toString();
        price_wash_iron = WashIronList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_WASH_IRON).toString();
        price_wash = WashList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_WASH).toString();
        price_iron = IronList.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE_IRON).toString();




        if (Cat_Position == 0) {
            //set item name
            ItemName.setText("" + Name);
            ItemPrice.setText("" + Price_Dry);
        } else if (Cat_Position == 1) {
            //set item name
            ItemName.setText("" + Name);
            ItemPrice.setText("" + price_wash_iron);
        } else if (Cat_Position == 2) {
            //set item name
            ItemName.setText("" + Name);
            ItemPrice.setText("" + price_wash);
        }else if (Cat_Position == 3) {
            //set item name
            ItemName.setText("" + Name);
            ItemPrice.setText("" + price_wash_iron);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

}